# WordPress if ( is_page( ) ) not fully working

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a question, I am trying to include some html on a particular page, the problem is when using  it displays nothing at all on that page.
On the other hand I already did the same thing inside of the same template for a different page and that worked out well.
I just don't seem to be able to get the same results again.
I wonder if those two functions are conflicting,
here is my code:

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: No Sidebar
 */
get_header();
?>
<?php if ( is_page('138') ) { ?> <!-- THIS WORKED FOR ME OK -->
    <!-- Plans -->
    <div id="plans" class="header-sales-page">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row header-sales-page-main-row">
                <!-- item -->
                <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
                    <div class="panel panel-danger panel-pricing">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h3>ESENCIAL</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body text-center panel-body-esencial">
                            <h2 class="non-suggested-price" >US$9,99 / Mes</h2><br>
                <p class="non-suggested-client-profile">Aficionado pero serio con tu voz</p>
                        </div>
                        <ul class="list-group text-center">
                            <li class="list-group-item avail">Módulo 2, 3, 4</li>
                <li class="list-group-item avail">1 Libro Electrónico <i class="tooltips fa fa-question-circle" title="Un libro que te enseña a cuidar tu voz para acelerar tu progreso como cantante"></i></li>
                <li class="list-group-item non-avail">10 Video-Lecciones Complementarias</li>
                <li class="list-group-item non-avail">Audio-Blogs Y Todas Las Actualizaciones</li>
                        </ul>
                        <div class="panel-footer">
                            <a class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-danger" id="select-esencial" href="#">SELECCIONAR</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /item -->
                <!-- item -->
                <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
                    <div class="panel panel-warning panel-pricing">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h3>ATV PLATINO</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body suggested text-center">
                            <h2 suggested-price>US$14,99 / Mes</h2><br>
                    <p class="non-suggested-client-profile" style="color:#fff;">Semi-Pro, ya es otra cosa!</p>
                        </div>
                        <ul class="list-group text-center">
                            <li class="list-group-item avail"> Módulo 2, 3, 4</li>
                <li class="list-group-item avail"> 2 Libros Electrónicos <i class="tooltips fa fa-question-circle" title="2 libros que te enseñan a cuidar tu voz y a entenderla para que aceleres tu progreso como cantante. "></i></li>
                <li class="list-group-item avail"> 3 Video-Lecciones<br> Complementarias <i class="tooltips fa fa-question-circle" title="Este material de refuerzo cubre dudas y complementa todo el material de vocalizaciones de tus módulos."></i></li>
                <li class="list-group-item non-avail">Audio-Blogs Y Todas Las Actualizaciones</li>
                        </ul>
                        <div class="panel-footer">
                            <a class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-warning" id="select-platino" href="#">SELECCIONAR</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /item -->
                <!-- item -->
                <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
                    <div class="panel panel-success panel-pricing">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h3>ATV PRO</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body text-center panel-body-pro">
                            <h2 class="non-suggested-price">US$19,99 / Mes</h2><br>
                    <p class="non-suggested-client-profile">Pro!! te he visto en la TV?</p>
                        </div>
                        <ul class="list-group text-center">
                            <li class="list-group-item avail"> Módulo 2, 3, 4</li>
                <li class="list-group-item avail"> 3 Libros Electrónicos
<i class="tooltips fa fa-question-circle" title="Tres libros que te enseñan a cuidar tu voz y a entenderla eliminando barreras psicológicas y acelerando tu progreso como cantante."></i></li>
                <li class="list-group-item avail"> 10 Video-Lecciones<br> Complementarias <i class="tooltips fa fa-question-circle" title="Este material de refuerzo cubre dudas y complementa todo el material de vocalizaciones de tus módulos."></i></li>
                <li class="list-group-item avail">Audio-Blogs Y Todas Las Actualizaciones  <i class="tooltips fa fa-question-circle" title="Blogs en audio y todo el material nuevo añadido a ATV sin costo adicional (no incluye módulos nuevos)"></i></li>
                        </ul>
                        <div class="panel-footer">
                            <a class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-success" id="select-pro" href="#">SELECCIONAR</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /item -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section">
        <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1">
                <h3>Prefieres un plan Anual?</h3>
                <div class="row plan-anual-second-row">
                    <div class="col-lg-2 rocket-div">
                        <i class="fa fa-rocket fa-3x"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-2 anual-prices">
                        <h4><strike>US$239,88</strike></h4>
                        <h4>US$119,99</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-6 anual-prices">
                        <h5>Adquiere acceso por un año entero con todos los beneficios del plan PRO ahorrando US$119,89</h5>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-2">
                        <a class="btn btn-md btn-block btn-success select-anual" id="select-anual" href="#">SELECCIONAR</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section faq">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <h5><strong>Tengo que preocuparme por ingresar pagos cada mes?</strong></h5>
<p>El sistema de suscripción se encarga de descontar de tu cuenta mensualmente (o anual si escogiste el plan anual) automáticamente.</p>
                <h5><strong>Puedo cambiar de plan?</strong></h5>
<p>Si, en cualquier momento. Tu cuenta simplemente adquiere las características y beneficios del plan al que cambiaste.</p>
                <h5><strong>Que pasa si cancelo mi plan?</strong></h5>
<p>Inmediatamente quedas en el plan gratuito que incluye Módulo 1.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <h5><strong>Que son actualizaciones?</strong></h5>
<p>Son materiales de estudio que se añaden de forma periódica a la plataforma ATV en formato de audio, PDF o video.</p>
                <h5><strong>Que es un libro electrónico?</strong></h5>
<p>Es un libro en formato PDF que puedes leer desde tu computador, tablet o dispositivo móvil.</p>
                <h5><strong>Que es un Audio Blog?</strong></h5>
<p>Audio Blogs son materiales de audio diferente a las vocalizaciones contenidas en los Módulos en que estos son material de audio que amplian el conocimento del cantante y no material para vocalizar.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
<?php } ?>  <!-- SO FAR SO GOOD -->
<?php if ( is_page('22438') ) { ?> <!-- BUT THEN THIS NEXT SECTION DID NOT WORK -->
    <div id="header"class="section header-sales-page">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row row-header-sales-page">
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-lg-offset-2 first-product-col">
                    <img src="http://cursos.tecnicadevoz.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/ATV-M2.jpg" class="img-responsive">
                    <div>
                        <h3>Módulo 2</h3>
                        <p>Módulo 1 puso el primer bloque para construir tu voz. M2 continúa poniendo en tu voz  el fundamento técnico que necesitas para ampliar tu rango vocal eliminando el dolor y la dificultad al cantar.<strong> 53 Tracks en 15 lecciones.</strong></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3">
                    <img src="http://cursos.tecnicadevoz.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/ATV-M3.jpg" class="img-responsive">
                    <div>
                        <h3>Módulo 3</h3>
                        <p>Refina el control de tu voz con vocalizaciones y escalas más sofisticadas que inducen y limpian tu vibrato y sustain vocal. <strong>52 Tracks en 16 lecciones.</strong></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3">
                    <img src="http://cursos.tecnicadevoz.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/ATV-Moduo-4.jpg" class="img-responsive">
                    <div>
                        <h3>Módulo 4</h3>
                        <p>Deja por sentada tu voz de cabeza legítima sin abuso ni dificultad al cantar notas agudas. Aprende a modificar las vocales para acceder notas agudas con facilidad y  aplicaciónes prácticas de la técnica en melodías.<strong>72 Tracks en 16 lecciones.</strong></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
<main class="site-content" role="main">
    <?php  if( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <header class="page-header">
        <div class="container">
            <?php the_title( '<h2 class="entry-title page-title">', '</h2>' ); ?>
        </div>
    </header>
    <?php endif; ?>
        <div id="primary" class="content-area">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div id="content" class="entry-content col-md-8 col-md-offset-2" role="main">
                    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() && !( is_search() || is_archive() ) ) : ?>
                    <div class="entry-featured-image">
                        <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'large' ); ?>
                    </div>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php the_content(); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!-- #primary -->
</main>
<?php
get_footer();
```

Thank you in advance I am a newby on this, so forgive my lack of articulation to explain my self.

Comment: Instead of this, why dont you create to 2 templates and assign to the respective pages?

Comment: Totally agree with above - especially as you are not reusing code at all in that template. Also if you use two templates you are not hard coding an id into your code which can only be a good thing :)

Answer (score 0):

In the above code you are passing id as a string

```
is_page('138')
```

**Instead you should do**

```
is_page(138)
```